# What are all the custom URL schemes supported by the Facebook iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api, deep-linking, undocumented-behavior

**Note**

> These URL's are likely not available.
>   Facebook has been updated a number of times and did not officially support any of these.

**/Note**

I am trying to see what information is available about the Facebook app on the iPhone. So far I have found a couple sites containing limited information, and I was able to figure out the Facebook Profile Publish command (unfortunately it keeps the window open after you post - so the person who publishes to Facebook has to push *post* once and then *cancel*).

My question is, does anyone have any more info on the commands that can be sent to the Facebook app?

The following information I was able to obtain from http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes

- `fb://profile` – Open Facebook app to the user’s profile.
- `fb://friends` – Open Facebook app to the friends list.
- `fb://notifications` – Open Facebook app to the notifications list (NOTE:  there appears to be a bug with this URL.  The Notifications page opens.  However, it’s not possible to navigate to anywhere else in the Facebook app)
- `fb://feed` – Open Facebook app to the News Feed.
- `fb://events` – Open Facebook app to the Events page.
- `fb://requests` – Open Facebook app to the Requests list.
- `fb://notes` – Open Facebook app to the Notes page.
- `fb://albums` – Open Facebook app to Photo Albums list.

These commands only open the corresponding windows.
The first useful command I found is

- `fb://publish/profile/#ID#?text=#BODY#`

this is a combination of the Facebook graph api and some other info I found on other application. Then a little poke and hope.

replace `#ID#` with the id of the profile you want to post to, then replace `#BODY#` with the text you want to post to, and the window shows up in facebook app with the text pre populated.

Also you can use `me` as an id to post to the signed-in user's profile.

If anyone knows any more I am trying to interface with it and would like as much information as possible.

Comment: I have tried doing this `fb://publish/profile/#me?text=someText` on iPad but it just open FB app without any post dialog. Do you know what's wrong with it?

Comment: I do not. Facebook has been updated a number of times since this posting and much of this may have been changed or removed completely.

Comment: You should add that disclaimer to the top of this post.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

**June 2014 EDIT**: Here is the updated list from Facebook v12:

```
fb://album?id=%@
fb://background_location
fb://browse?semantic=%@&result_type=%d&source_type=%d&title=%@
fb://codegenerator
fb://composer?%@
fb://composer?pagename=%@&pageid=%@
fb://composer?target=%@
fb://composer?view=location
fb://contactimporter/?ci_flow=%d
fb://discovery
fb://entitycards/?ids=%@&source=%@
fb://event?id=%@
fb://event?id=%@&post_id=%@
fb://eventguestlist?event_id=%@
fb://events/list
fb://eventslist?owner_fbid=%@
fb://f(.+)(\?|&)v=map(\&.*)?
fb://f(.+)incorrect_map_pin(\&.*)?
fb://friendsnearby
fb://friendsnearby/?source=%@
fb://friendsnearby/?source=divebar
fb://friendsnearby/ping?fbid=%@&source=%@
fb://friendsnearby/profile?fbid=%@&source=%@
fb://gift?
fb://group?id=%@
fb://group?id=%@&object_id=%@&view=permalink
fb://hashtag/
fb://hashtag/%@
fb://location_settings
fb://messageComposer?
fb://messaging/new
fb://messaging/new?id=%@&name=%@&isPage=%d
fb://messaging?
fb://messaging?id=%@
fb://messaging?id=%@&%@
fb://messaging?tid=%@
fb://messaginglist
fb://page?id=%@
fb://page?id=%@&source=%@&source_id=%@
fb://page_about?id=%@
fb://page_friend_likes_and_visits?id=%@
fb://page_reviews?id=%@
fb://photo?%@
fb://photo?id=%@
fb://pnp?type=instructions
fb://products?%@
fb://profile
fb://profile/%@
fb://profile?id=%@
fb://profile?id=%@&%@=%@
fb://story?%@
fb://story?graphqlid=%@
fb://story?id=%@
fb://timelineappsection?id=%@
fb://topic/%@
fb://uploadcoverphoto
fb://zrnext
```

**April 2013 EDIT** : Looks like none of below works anymore with latest versions, facebook app *navigation* probably has been rewrited. Some reverse engineering to do on latest version...

I guess that might help, that's from v3.4 :

```
fb://album/%@
fb://album/(aid)
fb://album/(aid)/cover
fb://album/(initWithAID:)
fb://album/(initWithAID:)/cover
fb://album/new
fb://albums
fb://birthdays
fb://birthdays/(initWithMonth:)/(year:)
fb://birthdays/(month)/(year)
fb://chat/(fbid)
fb://chat/(initWithUID:)
fb://chat/(user.fbid)
fb://contactimporter
fb://contactimporter/invites
fb://contactimporter/legalese
fb://contactimporter/modal
fb://event/%@
fb://event/%llu
fb://event/(event.fbid)/members/(rsvpStatus)
fb://event/(fbid)
fb://event/(fbid)/members/attending
fb://event/(fbid)/members/declined
fb://event/(fbid)/members/not_replied
fb://event/(fbid)/members/unsure
fb://event/(fbid)/rsvp
fb://event/(initWithEventId:)
fb://event/(initWithEventId:)/members/(rsvpStatus:)
fb://event/(initWithEventId:)/rsvp
fb://events
fb://events/
fb://faceweb/(initWithURL:)
fb://facewebmodal/(initWithURL:)
fb://feed
fb://feed/%@
fb://feed/(filter.filterKey)
fb://feed/(initWithFilterKey:)
fb://feedfilters
fb://findfriends
fb://findfriends/legalese
fb://findfriends/modal
fb://friends
fb://friends/picker
fb://friends/sync
fb://friends/sync/(removeData:)
fb://friends/sync/disconnect
fb://friends/sync/legalese
fb://group/(fbid)/members
fb://group/(initWithGroupId:)/members
fb://groups
fb://launcher
fb://mailbox
fb://mailbox/(folder)
fb://mailbox/(initWithFolder:)
fb://mailbox/(initWithFolder:)/(tid:)
fb://mailbox/(mailbox.folder)/(tid)
fb://mailbox/compose
fb://mailbox/compose/(fbid)
fb://mailbox/compose/(initWithUID:)
fb://map
fb://messaging
fb://messaging/(folder)
fb://messaging/(initWithFolder:)
fb://messaging/(initWithFolder:)/(tid:)/participants
fb://messaging/(initWithFolder:)/thread?tid=(tid:)
fb://messaging/(mailbox.folder)/(urlEscapedTid)/participants
fb://messaging/(mailbox.folder)/thread?tid=(urlEscapedTid)
fb://messaging/compose
fb://messaging/compose/(fbid)
fb://messaging/compose/(initWithUID:)
fb://messaging/original_message?mid=(commentId)
fb://messaging/original_message?mid=(initWithMessageId:)
fb://nearby
fb://note/%@
fb://note/(initWithNoteId:)
fb://note/(initWithNoteId:)/edit
fb://note/(noteId)
fb://note/(noteId)/edit
fb://note/compose
fb://notes
fb://notifications
fb://online
fb://online#offline
fb://online#online
fb://page/(page.id)
fb://pages
fb://photo/%@/0/%@
fb://photo/(album.user.fbid)/(album.aid)/(pid)
fb://photo/(album.user.fbid)/(album.aid)/(pid)/feedback
fb://photo/(fbid)/profilepic
fb://photo/(initWithProfilePicturesUID:)/profilepic
fb://photo/(initWithUID:)/(aid:)/(pid:)
fb://photo/(initWithUID:)/(aid:)/(pid:)/feedback
fb://photosapp
fb://place/%@
fb://place/(initWithPageId:)
fb://place/(targetId)
fb://place/addfriends
fb://place/addphoto
fb://place/create
fb://places
fb://places/%lld/%lld
fb://places/(initWithCheckinAtPlace:)/(byUser:)
fb://places/legalese/tagged/%lld/%lld
fb://places/legalese/tagged/(initWithTaggedAtPlace:)/(byUser:)
fb://post/%@
fb://post/%@_%@
fb://post/(initWithPostId:)
fb://post/(initWithPostId:)/tagged
fb://post/(postId)
fb://post/(postId)/tagged
fb://post/(postId)/untagSelf
fb://post/(untagSelfFromPostWithId:)/untagSelf
fb://profile
fb://profile/
fb://profile/%@
fb://profile/%lld
fb://profile/(addFan:)/addfan
fb://profile/(fbid)
fb://profile/(fbid)/addfan
fb://profile/(fbid)/addfriend
fb://profile/(fbid)/fanpages
fb://profile/(fbid)/fans
fb://profile/(fbid)/favorite
fb://profile/(fbid)/friends
fb://profile/(fbid)/info
fb://profile/(fbid)/menu
fb://profile/(fbid)/mutualfriends
fb://profile/(fbid)/photos
fb://profile/(fbid)/poke
fb://profile/(fbid)/removefriend
fb://profile/(fbid)/wall
fb://profile/(initWithFBID:)/menu
fb://profile/(initWithFansUID:)/fans
fb://profile/(initWithFriendsUID:)/friends
fb://profile/(initWithInfoUID:)/info
fb://profile/(initWithMutualFriendsUID:)/mutualfriends
fb://profile/(initWithPhotosUID:)/photos
fb://profile/(initWithUID:)
fb://profile/(initWithUID:)/addfriend
fb://profile/(initWithUID:)/fanpages
fb://profile/(initWithUID:)/poke
fb://profile/(initWithUID:)/removefriend
fb://profile/(initWithWallUID:)/wall
fb://profile/(toggleFavorite:)/favorite
fb://profile/(user.fbid)/fans
fb://profile/(user.fbid)/friends
fb://profile/(user.fbid)/mutualfriends
fb://profile/0
fb://publish
fb://publish/mailbox/(initWithFolder:)/(tid:)
fb://publish/mailbox/(mailbox.folder)/(tid)
fb://publish/photo/(album.user.fbid)/(album.aid)/(pid)
fb://publish/photo/(initWithUID:)/(aid:)/(pid:)
fb://publish/post/(initWithPostId:)
fb://publish/post/(postId)
fb://publish/profile/(fbid)
fb://publish/profile/(initWithUID:)
fb://publish/profile/(owner.fbid)
fb://requests
fb://root
fb://upload
fb://upload/%@/album/%lld/%@
fb://upload/%@/checkin/%lld
fb://upload/%@/profile/%lld
fb://upload/(initWithSource:)/album/(uid:)/(aid:)
fb://upload/(initWithSource:)/checkin/(checkinId:)
fb://upload/(initWithSource:)/profile/(uid:)
fb://upload/actions
fb://upload/actions/album/(initWithUID:)/(aid:)
fb://upload/actions/album/(user.fbid)/(aid)
fb://upload/actions/checkin/(checkinId)/
fb://upload/actions/checkin/(initWithCheckinId:)
fb://upload/actions/newalbum
fb://upload/actions/profile/(fbid)
fb://upload/actions/profile/(initWithUID:)
fb://upload/actions/resume
fb://upload/album/(showUploadMenuWithUID:)/(aid:)
fb://upload/album/(user.fbid)/(aid)
fb://upload/checkin/(checkinId)
fb://upload/checkin/(showUploadMenuWithCheckinID:)
fb://upload/discard
fb://upload/profile/(fbid)
fb://upload/profile/(owner.fbid)
fb://upload/profile/(showUploadMenuWithUID:)
fb://upload/resume
fb://userset
fb://video/%@
fb://video/(playVideoWithId:)
fb://video/(videoId)
```

Comment: How, or where did you get that information ? I have yet to find more information then what I have listed above.... is there a place this information is put. or a way to get it out of the application itself?

Comment: this information comes from the Facebook binary : `strings Facebook | grep 'fb://' | sort | uniq`. To get more informations would probably involve reversing (assembly) code unless you got a friend working at Facebook

Comment: do you need your phone rooted to access that ?

Comment: Is it just me or do many of these not seem to work anymore? fb://profile/146152962128830 works for my works fanpage, but fb://profile/146152962128830/wall doesn't for example. Nor does addfan, fans etc etc...

Comment: it is up to facebook weather they respond to these commands or not. I have abandoned the usage of the facebook app entirely. Now I just do my posting through the webpage.

Comment: @Rog thanks for editing list, but what Facebook version is it?

Comment: @VincentG Was wondering if you knew where to get a bit of information about these intents, especially concerning the fb://photo/(album.user.fbid)/(album.aid)/(pid)

Comment: Just a quick note to say that I tried /publish/profile/me, /albums, /requests and /friends from iOS 6 Safari and FB app version 144493 today and none worked.

Comment: This info is kind of worthless for many cases. Official information, or misinformation. Because this stuff could change at any point. Trying to open "Facebook page" ATM but nothing works. The best bet for now seems to be linking to m.facebook.com/, so that Safari opens.

Comment: @VincentGuerci so is it possible with current version to `publish` anything in this way? Does exist any workaround for example for this kind of action `fb://publish/profile/me?text=foo`?

Comment: Anyone know if these are safe to use? Since they're officially undocumented, I would assume that they are NOT safe and could change at any time.

Comment: I think this is an incorrect way of doing business. If it's not official, go do something else. Anyway thank for hte urls :-)

Comment: Just a heads up, none of these work anymore as of Sep. 23rd 2015. Only ``fb://`` with no arguments whatsoever.

Comment: what are possible parameters in this fb://app_section/%s/%s

Comment: To open a specific post use the fb://story handler: fb://story?id=IDENTIFIER

Comment: @toto:your comment save me.

Comment: Hey, @VincentGuerci please suggest me a fb URL to share a fb-page or website, I got confused which one will work for that

Comment: @NeerajRathod were you able to figure out a solution? I am stuck with the same issue now..

Comment: @VincentGuerci I am tried for the open Facebook group.
can you help me, this is my url.
 fb://group?id=battlboxmembersonly

Answer (score 48):

1. Because the accepted answer is not a CW, I'm adding updates separately.
2. These are taken from **Android**, but should be the same for iOS.
3. This list has reached the length limitation of a SO post (30k characters), so further updates will be posted in a different medium, specified at a later date.

---

**October 2017 Update (from Facebook Messenger v141.0.0.25.76):**

> #### Unless otherwise specified, links below should begin with `fb://`

```
fb-service://limit_friend_requests

about
account/recovery
account_settings
account-kit/confirmation_code/?confirmation_code={confirmation_code}
achievements/landing/?achievement_id=%s&source=%s
activitylog
ad_activity
ad_break/admin_preview/?video_id=%s&time_offset=%s
add_address/
add_services
ads/preferences/?tracking=%s
ads_checkout_payment_receipt?account=%s&campaignGroupID=%s&chargeAmount=%s&chargeCurrency=%s&orderNumber=%s&credentialID=%s&timeCreated=%s&withdrawAmount=%s&withdrawCurrency=%s
ads_experience/?id=%s
ads_payments_add_bank_account?account=%s&contextID=%s&originRootTag=%s
ads_payments_add_card?account=%s&contextID=%s&dismissOnCompletion=%s&isCheckout=%s&isPUX=%s
ads_payments_add_card?account=%s&isCheckout=%s&dismissOnCompletion=%s&contextID=%s
ads_payments_add_credit_card?account=%s&contextID=%s&originRootTag=%s&offlineMode=%s&legacyAccountID=%s&country=%s&currency=%s
ads_payments_add_paypal?account=%s&contextID=%s&originRootTag=%s
ads_payments_billing_date?account=%s&contextID=%s&hasIntent=%s
ads_payments_billing_date_saved?account=%s&contextID=%s
ads_payments_brazil_address_info?account=%s&contextID=%s&taxID=%s
ads_payments_brazil_tax_id?account=%s&contextID=%s
ads_payments_checkout?account=%s&page=%s&boostMessage=%s&boostImageURI=%s&boostResultType=%s&boostResultLowerBound=%s&boostResultUpperBound=%s&boostDuration=%s&budgetAmount=%s&budgetCurrency=%s&budgetType=%s&credentialID=%s&cachedCscToken=%s&contextID=%s&campaignGroupID=%s&cardType=%s&cardAssociationImageURL=%s&lastFourDigits=%s&expiryMonth=%s&expiryYear=%s&newEndTime=%s&editTime=%s
ads_payments_checkout?account=%s&page=%s&boostMessage=%s&boostImageURI=%s&boostResultType=%s&boostResultLowerBound=%s&boostResultUpperBound=%s&boostDuration=%s&budgetAmount=%s&budgetCurrency=%s&budgetType=%s&credentialID=%s&cachedCscToken=%s&contextID=%s&cardType=%s&cardAssociationImageURL=%s&lastFourDigits=%s&expiryMonth=%s&expiryYear=%s&campaignGroupID=%s&newEndTime=%s&editTime=%s
ads_payments_checkout_receipt?account=%s&campaignGroupID=%s
ads_payments_country_selector?account=%s&contextID=%s&offlineMode=%s&countryCode=%s&currencyCode=%s
ads_payments_currency_selector?account=%s&contextID=%s&selectedCurrency=%s
ads_payments_direct_debit_country_selector?account=%s&contextID=%s&countryCode=%s
ads_payments_flow?account=%s&contextID=%s&adBudgetAmountInHundredths=%s&adBudgetType=%s&adDuration=%s&adCampaignGroupID=%s&adEditTime=%s&adNewEndTime=%s&offlineMode=%s&legacyAccountID=%s&addPaymentMethodMessage=%s&disableCouponEntry=%s&countryCode=%s&currencyCode=%s&boostAfterComplete=%s&pageID=%s
ads_payments_gst_id?account=%s&contextID=%s
ads_payments_prepay_business_info?account=%s&contextID=%s&originRootTag=%s
ads_payments_prepay_client_info?account=%s&contextID=%s&originRootTag=%s&businessTaxID=%s&businessEuVatTaxCountry=%s&businessName=%s&businessStreet1=%s&businessStreet2=%s&businessCity=%s&businessState=%s&businessZip=%s&businessCountryCode=%s
ads_payments_prepay_disclaimer?account=%s&contextID=%s&originRootTag=%s
ads_payments_prepay_funding?account=%s&contextID=%s&originRootTag=%s
adsmanager/%s/billing/settle
adsmanager/%s/detailed_targeting/%s/%s/%s/%s/%s/%s/%s?isModal=%s
adsmanager/%s/insights/%s
adsmanager/{account}/insights/{adObject}
adsmanager/{account}/insights/{adObject}?account=%s&adObject=%s&editCampaignURI=%s&shouldShowAdHeaderView=%s&adObjectLevel=%s
adsmanager/image/select/%s
adsmanager/image/select/{page}
adsmanager/image/select/{page}?page=%s&cropWidth=%s&cropHeight=%s&minCropWidth=%s&minCropHeight=%s&callbackModule=%s&callbackMethod=%s&imageSourceCategory=%s&isInstagramEnabled=%s&account=%s
albumcreator
albumcreator?featured={is_featured}
albums
albums/%s
albums/%s?tab_to_land=%s
albums_edit_flow
ama?entryPoint=%s&fb_hidesTabBar=%s&presentationMethod=%s&targetURI=%s
ama?entryPoint=%s&targetURI=%s
app_section/%s/%s
appcenter
appcenter/detail?app_id=%s
appfeed
appinvites/
background_location/nux?source=%s&redirect_after_accept=%s&nux_type=%s
background_location/settings
beam/receiver?ssid=%s&code=%s&timestamp=%d
bi_boosted_post_appeal_form/?boost_id={boost_id}
booking_request/create_appointment
booking_request/create_appointment?booking_request_id=%s
bookmarks/
bookmarks_section
boost_event/?page_id=%s&graphql_story_id=%s&promotion_target_id=%s&placement_extra=%s&referral=%s&coupon_promotion_group_id=%s&ad_account_id=%s&scroll_to_section=%s&request_data=%s
boost_post/?page_id=%s&graphql_story_id=%s&referral=%s&coupon_promotion_group_id=%s&ad_account_id=%s&scroll_to_section=%s&request_data=%s
bootcamp/
camera
canvaseditor?canvas=%s&page_id=%s&story=%s&source=%s
casual_groups_tab
cityguides?pageID=%s&pageName=%s&entryPoint=%s
codegenerator
collection/%s/%s/%s
commerce/admin/products/%s/edit
commerce/admin/products/add
commerce/admin/shop/%s/add
commerce/admin/shop/%s/edit
commerce/collectionview/%s
commerce/collectionview/%s?rid=%s&rt=%s&title=%s&hide_page_header=%s
commerce/contact-merchant/dialog?<q$1>
commerce/products/%s
commerce/products/%s?rid=%s&rt=%s&preview_details=%s
commerce/products/<p$1>
commerce/shop/%s
commerce/shop/%s?rid=%s&rt=%s&selected_product_id=%s&hide_page_header=%s
commerce/shop/visual-search/camera
commerce_inventory?groupID=%s
commerce_inventory_comments?storyID=%s
commerce_inventory_cross_post?storyID=%s
component_script_playground
composer
composer?view=live&text={?text}
contextual_profile/{#com.facebook.katana.profile.id}
coverphoto
creatorapp/home/following
cta_promotion?page_id=%s&boost_id=%s&source=%s&referral=%s&restore_saved_settings=%s&coupon_promotion_group_id=%s&ad_account_id=%s&scroll_to_section=%s&request_data=%s
daily_dialogue_weather_permalink
daily_dialogue_weather_permalink?city_id=%s
daily_dialogue_weather_permalink?city_id=%s&orig_src=%s
daily_dialogue_weather_permalink?orig_src=%s
data_savings_mode_settings
data_savings_mode_settings/?source=bar
data_savings_mode_settings/?source=bookmarks
data_savings_upsell
dbl_loggedin_settings
dbl_login_activity
device_requests
dialtone_info_screen
direct_inbox/
direct_viewer/source/{source}
direct_viewer/source/{source}/direct_thread_id/{direct_thread_id}
ditto_timeline/{#com.facebook.katana.profile.id}
donate/?fundraiser_campaign_id=%1$s&action_type=%2$s
donate/?fundraiser_campaign_id=%1$s&post_id=%2$s
donate/?fundraiser_campaign_id=%1$s&post_id=0
donate/?fundraiser_campaign_id=%1$s&source=%2$s
donate?fundraiser_campaign_id=%1$s&source=%2$s
donate_create
donate_create/?force_create_form=true
donate_create/?fundraiser_campaign_id=%1$s&source=%2$s
donate_create/?fundraiser_charity_id=%1$s&source=%2$s
donate_create/?fundraiser_charity_id=%1$s&source=%2$s&promotional_source=%3$s
donate_create/?source=%1$s
donate_guestlist/?fundraiser_campaign_id=%1$s
donate_invite/?fundraiser_campaign_id=%1$s
donate_invite/?fundraiser_campaign_id=%1$s&source=%2$s
donate_invite_new
donate_single_click_invite/?fundraiser_campaign_id=%1$s
donate_single_click_invite/?fundraiser_campaign_id=%1$s&source=%2$s
donate_single_click_invite/?fundraiser_campaign_id=%1$s&source=%2$s&referral_source=%3$s
donate_trigger/?id=%1$s
donate_trigger/?id=%1$s&source=%2$s
editor?entry_point={entry_point}
electionHub
electionHub/?ref=search
event/%s
event/%s/extendedinvite
event/%s/invite
event/%s/invitegroup/%s
event/%s/makeplans?__referral_surface=%s&__referral_mechanism=%s
event/%s/messagefriends/asgroup?__referral_surface=%s&__referral_mechanism=%s
event/%s/messagefriends?__referral_surface=%s&__referral_mechanism=%s
event/{event_id}/messageallfriends?__referral_surface={ref_surface}&__referral_mechanism={ref_mechanism}
event_collection
event_creation
event_creation/%s
event_creation/{#%s}
event_creation/categories
event_creation/details
event_creation/notification?story_cache_id=%s
event_creation/prefill/%s
event_creation?privacy={%s}
event_discovery
event_discovery/filter?title={%s}&suggestion_context={%s}
event_edit
event_stories_review_sheet?eventID={event_id}&bucketID={bucket_id}
events
events/%s/timeslots
events/{%s}/reaction
events/campaign?suggestion_token={suggestion_token}&title={title}&ref_notif_type={ref_notif_type}&ref_surface={ref_surface}&ref_mechanism={ref_mechanism}
events/section?section_name=%s
explore/
facecast_integrated_sharesheet/
facecast_sharesheet/
facerec_enrollment_setting
facerec_settings
faceweb/f?href=
faceweb/f?href=%%2Fprofile.php?v=info%%26id=%s
faceweb/f?href=%2Ffriends%2Fcenter%2Ffriends%2F
faceweb/f?href=%2Fhelp%2Fwork
faceweb/f?href=%2Fmessages?src=fb4a
faceweb/f?href=%2Fnearby_info%2Fmanage_hidden_pages
faceweb/f?href=%2Fonavo/promotion/install
faceweb/f?href=%2Fprivacy
faceweb/f?href=%2Fprivacy%2Ftouch%2Ftimeline_and_tagging
faceweb/f?href=%2Fsaved
faceweb/f?href=%s
faceweb/f?href=%s&force_faceweb=true
faceweb/f?href=//settings/location/learnmore
faceweb/f?href=/ads/manager
faceweb/f?href=/commerce/contact-merchant/dialog/?product_item_id=%s
faceweb/f?href=/coupons/info/?coupon_id=%s
faceweb/f?href=/event/%s/madminpanel/pending
faceweb/f?href=/groups
faceweb/f?href=/instant_article/publisher_ad_about
faceweb/f?href=/media/set/?set=ft.%s
faceweb/f?href=/pages/create/?ref_type=android_timeline
faceweb/f?href=/pages/messaging/action/compose/?post_id=%s
faceweb/f?href=/pages/place_claim/entry_redirect/?page_id=%s
faceweb/f?href=/profile/intro/edit/about
faceweb/f?href=/profile/intro/edit/links
faceweb/f?href=/settings/email
faceweb/f?href=/timeline/friend_list_view/?profile_id=%s
faceweb/f?href=https://m.facebook.com/jobs?source=%s
faceweb/f?href=https://m.facebook.com/onthisday/notification/settings/?source=permalink
faceweb/f?href=https://m.facebook.com/onthisday/preferences/?source=permalink
faceweb/f?href=https://m.facebook.com/order_tracking
faceweb/f?href=https://m.facebook.com/work/terms/nav
facewebmodal/f?href=%s
family_nav_instagram_install
fb_photos_picker
fb_photos_picker/?campaign=%s
feed
feed_awesomizer
feed_awesomizer/connections
feed_awesomizer/following
feed_awesomizer/see_first
feed_awesomizer/unfollowed
feed_switcher?switcher_item_id={%s}
findfriends/learn_more
findfriends?ci_flow=%s
findfriends?ci_flow=%s&ccu_ref=%s&force_show_legal_screen=true
findfriends?ci_flow=%s&force_show_legal_screen=true
findwifi
findwifi_nux
findwifi_settings
flex_dsm_settings
free_fb_invite
friending_possibilities?location=%s
friendlist/%s
friends/
friends/center?source_ref=%s
friends/center?source_ref=%s&fc_tab=%s
friends/center?source_ref=%s&fc_tab=requests&user_id=%s&name=%s&profile_pic=%s&attachment=%s
friends/new_user_promotion
friends/requests/
friends/requests_tab
friendship/%s/%s
friendsnearby/profile?fbid=%s&source=%s&notif_id=%s
friendsnearby?source=%s
friendsnearby_invite?selected=%s&excluded=%s
fullscreen_video/{video_id}?loop={loop}
fullscreen_video_redirect/{%s}
fullscreen_video_redirect/{%s}?threadid={%s}
fundraiser_beneficiary_other_input
fundraiser_beneficiary_search/?launch_state=%1$s&beneficiary_type=%2$s
fundraiser_beneficiary_search/?launch_state=%1$s&beneficiary_type=%2$s&source=%3$s
fundraiser_category_selector
fundraiser_country_selector
fundraiser_creation_suggested_cover_photo
fundraiser_currency_selector
fundraiser_submitted/?fundraiser_campaign_id=%1$s&is_p4p=%2$s
fundraisers_shell/?targetURI=%1$s
getgames
getquote/%s/form_builder
gift/receive?gid=%s
gltf_fullscreen
graph_editor?entry_point={entry_point}
group/%s
group/%s/?group_tip_id=%s
group/%s?group_view_referrer=%s
group_commerce_bookmark_category_feed_route?referralSurface+%s
group_commerce_bookmark_category_route?referralSurface=%s&categoryId=%s
group_commerce_bookmark_route?referralSurface=%s
group_commerce_message_seller_route?groupCommerceProductItemID=%s
groups/chats
groups/chats/%s
groups/create
groups/create?ref=%s
groups/createtab
groups/discover
groups/discover/categories
groups/discover/category?id={%s}
groups/discover/tag?id=%s
groups/events/{%s}
groups/gridtab
groups/link
groups/members/{%s}
groups/photos/{%s}
groups/questionnaire/%s
groups/suggestions?source=%s
groups_discovery
groups_targeted_tab
gv_editor?campaign_id=%s&campaign_type=%s&editor_type=%s&initial_source=%s&direct_source=%s
gv_share/?campaign_id=%s&campaign_type=%s&initial_source=%s&direct_source=%s&share_preview=%s&share_preview_title=%s
gv_share/?campaign_id=%s&campaign_type=%s&initial_source=%s&direct_source=%s&share_preview=%s&share_preview_title=%s&share_autofill=%s
hashtag/%s?name=%s&id=%s
help
hyperlocal_discovery?place_id={place_id}&trigger_type={trigger_type}
id_backed_privacy_checkup_react/?checkup_id=%s
ig_sign_up_creation
immersive_capture_sharesheet/
inspiration_settings/
inspirationscamera/?effectID={?effect_id}&reason={?reason}&shareActorID={?share_actor_id}&shareTargetID={?share_target_id}&shouldDisplayCameraRollEffectTooltip={?should_display_camera_roll_effect_tooltip}&categoryID={?category_id}&inspiration_post_action={?inspiration_post_action}&cameraFlow={?camera_flow}
instagram_ci_sso?entry_point={entry_point}
instant_articles
instant_shopping_catalog/?catalog_id={%s -1}&catalog_view={%s -1}&product_id={%s -1}&product_view={%s -1}
invite_coworker
jobApplication?job_opening_id=%s
jobApplication?job_opening_id=%s&source=%s
jobApplication?job_opening_id=%s&source=%s&waterfall_session_id=%s
jobApplicationForm?job_opening_id=%s
jobATSApplication?job_application_id=%s&source=%s
jobOpeningATSRoute?job_opening_id=%s&source=%s
jobSearch
jobSearch?pinned_job_opening_id=%s&source=%s
jobSearch?source=%s
jobSearch?waterfall_session_id=%s&source=%s
language_in_videos_picker
language_switch
lead_gen/?lead_gen_data_id=%s
leadgen?formID=%s&adID=%s&app=%s&mediaID=%s&actorID=%s&trackingToken=%s&brandingImageURI=%s&relayFunnelTag=%s&dynamicItemID=%s
legacy_contact/%s
legacy_contact/%s/cover_photo/
legacy_contact/%s/friend_requests/
legacy_contact/%s/profile_picture/
lh_prompt
lifebalance
link_fb_invite
local_awareness_promotion/?page_id=%s&boost_id=%s&source=%s&referral=%s&restore_saved_settings=%s&coupon_promotion_group_id=%s&ad_account_id=%s&scroll_to_section=%s&request_data=%s
localsell_home/?tabIndex=%s&referralSurface=%s
location_settings
location_timeline
location_timeline_nux
logged_out_push_interstitial
loginapprovalspush
loyalty_add_point_or_redeem
loyalty_admin_phone_number_qr_code_selection?programID={programID}&programTitle={programTitle}
loyalty_admin_result
loyalty_admin_status?pageID={pageID}
loyalty_home?referrer=bookmarks
loyalty_kiosk
ls_prompt
maps
marketplace
marketplace?referralSurface=%s
marketplace_buy_sell_group_home
marketplace_category_deep_link
marketplace_category_menu
marketplace_category_search
marketplace_composer/?assetIDs=%s&defaultCategoryID=%s
marketplace_crosspost
marketplace_debug_info_details
marketplace_drafts
marketplace_editcomposer/?storyID=%s&referralSurface=%s&isDraft=%s
marketplace_forsalegroupshome
marketplace_forsalegroupshome_story
marketplace_home
marketplace_inactive_items
marketplace_initial_message
marketplace_location
marketplace_message
marketplace_message/?threadID=%s&referralSurface=%s
marketplace_multi_theme_feed
marketplace_notification_settings
marketplace_notifications
marketplace_photo_chooser_composer
marketplace_product_details
marketplace_product_details?id=%s&referralSurface=%s
marketplace_product_details_from_post_id?post_id=%s
marketplace_product_message_threads
marketplace_product_message_threads/?productTitle=%s&productID=%s&referralSurface=%s
marketplace_profile?id=%s
marketplace_saved
marketplace_saved_search_results
marketplace_search
marketplace_search?query=%s&referralSurface=%s
marketplace_seller_item_details
marketplace_seller_item_details/?productTitle=%s&forSaleItemID=%s&referralSurface=%s
marketplace_shops?refID=%s&refType=%s&categoryIDs=%s&browseContext=%s
marketplace_theme_feed
marketplace_top_sellers
marketplace_your_items
mediaset/brpi.%s
mediaset/brpo.%s
mentorship_expectation?memberId=%s&groupId=%s&programId=%s&role=%s
mentorship_home
mentorship_meet_mentee?memberId=%s&groupId=%s&programId=%s&role=%s
mentorship_welcome?memberId=%s&groupId=%s&programId=%s&role=%s
menu_management?page_id=%s
merchant_onboarding_currency?refID=%s&refType=%s&paymentProvider=%s&pageID=%s
merchant_onboarding_shop_type?refID=%s&refType=%s&pageID=%s
merchant_onboarding_terms?refID=%s&refType=%s&pageID=%s
messaging
messaging/
messaging/%s
messaging/active_now/
messaging/compose/
messaging/compose/%s
messaging/compose/new
messaging/compose/new/group
messaging/groupthreadfbid/
messaging/groupthreadfbid/%s
messaging/thread/thread?id=
messaging/thread/thread?id=%s
messaging_lite
messaging_tab
messaging_threadlist
mobileconfigrnconfigparams?title=%s&overridden=%s
mobileconfigrnparamoverride?configName=%s&title=%s
mobileconfigrntroubleshooting?configName=%s&title=%s
mobileconfigrnui
mobileconfigrnvalue
movies_theater_select_flow?movie_flow_service_config_id=%s&movie_event_external_movie_id=%s
movieshome
native_album/%s
native_article?article={%s}
native_article?article={%s}&canonical={%s}
native_article?article={%s}&canonical={%s}&saved={%s}
native_article?article={%s}&canonical={%s}&saved={%s}&featured={%s}
native_document/?id={%s -1}
native_post/%s
native_post/%s?fallback_url=%s
native_post/%s?story_cache_id=%s
native_template_shell/?id=throwback/camera/preference?device_id=%s&analytics=throwback/camera/preference
nativename
nearby
nearby/search
nearby/subcategory
nearbyInfoSettings
neo/fallback
neo/fallback?target=friending
neo/fallback?target=hub
neo/fallback?target=profile
neo_friending
neo_hub
neo_profile
neo_profile?fbid=%s&referrer=%s
newContactPoint
nfx?object_id=%s
nfx?object_id=%s&location=%s
note/%s
notification_settings
notification_settings_add_contact_point?contact_type={contact_type}
notification_settings_alerts
notification_settings_confirm_contact_point
notification_settings_email
notification_settings_phone_number
notification_settings_push_and_sounds
notifications
notifications_friending
notifications_griffin
notifications_tab
now/
nux/profile_picture?external_photo_source=%s
offers/barcode_fullscreen/?title=%s&extra_image_url=%s
offers/detail/?coupon_id=%s
offers/detail/view/?offer_view_id=%s&share_id=%s&redirect=%s
offers/detail/view/?offer_view_id=%s&share_id=%s&redirect=%s&offer_should_claim=%s&offer_location=%s
offers/wallet
offlinefeed
onavo_protect_interstitial
online
onthisday?source=%s
onthisday?source=%s&campaign_id=%s&story_id=%s
order_food_see_all
page/%s
page/%s/admin_feed
page/%s/admin_stories
page/%s/album_list
page/%s/book_appointment?referrer=%s
page/%s/book_appointment?referrer=%s&service_id=%s
page/%s/call_to_action
page/%s/child_locations
page/%s/clips
page/%s/community
page/%s/config_call_to_action/%s?ref=%s
page/%s/configure_action
page/%s/episodes
page/%s/events_list
page/%s/get_quote
page/%s/info
page/%s/insights
page/%s/invite_friends_to_like_page
page/%s/jobs
page/%s/offers
page/%s/pendingedits
page/%s/playlists
page/%s/reaction
page/%s/recommendations
page/%s/residence
page/%s/service/%s
page/%s/services_list
page/%s/services_list?entry_point=%s
page/%s/share_as_message
page/%s/suggestedit?entry_point=%s
page/%s/videohub
page/%s/videolist?page_id=%s&source=%s
page/%s/vistor_posts
page/%s?referrer=%s&admin_guidance_type=%s
page/{#arg_page_id}/call_to_action/{arg_page_call_to_action_id}?action_channel_type={arg_action_channel_type}&action_type={arg_action_type}&action_position={#arg_action_position}&page_call_to_action_ref={?arg_page_call_to_action_ref}&page_view_ref={?arg_page_view_ref}
page/{%s}/tab/{%s}
page/appointment_calendar
page/appointment_calendar?referrer=settings
page/calendar_setting_host
page/comparison?comparison_card_type={arg_comparison_card_type}&placelist_id={arg_placelist_id}&page_id={arg_page_id}&comment_graphql_id={arg_comment_graphql_id}
page/consumer_appointment_detail?appointment_id=%s
page/create_new_page/?ref=%s
page/deeplink/%s/tab/%s
page/message_settings?type=all&ref=%s
page/message_settings?type=follow_up&ref=%s&should_enable=%s
page/message_settings?type=reminder_message&ref=%s
page/messages/%s
page/service_selector
page/services_messagner_appointments_cta_creation?page_id=%s
page/video_type
page/videolist?page_id=%s&source=%s
page/videolist?page_id={%s}&source={%s}
page/voice_switcher
page_admin_appointment_request_detail
page_like_promotion/?page_id=%s&boost_id=%s&source=%s&referral=%s&restore_saved_settings=%s&coupon_promotion_group_id=%s&ad_account_id=%s&scroll_to_section=%s&request_data=%s
page_link_menu_management?page_id=%s
page_locations_map/?page_id={page_id}&page_name={page_name}&latitude={?latitude}&longitude={?longitude}&locations_count={locations_count}
pages
pages/%s/enable_server_calendar_export?provider=%s&ref=%s
pages/%s/upsell_calendar_export?booking_request_id=%s&calendar_status=%s&ref=%s
pages/?category=%s
pages/create
pages/launchpoint
pages/messaging/private_reply/dialog/%s/%s
pagesadminhelp
pagesadminlaunchpoint
pagestab
payment_settings
payment_settings_rn
photo/%s
photo/%s/?set=%s
photo_checkup/?source=%s&checkup_type=%s
photo_menu/?page_id=%s
photo_menu/add/?page_id=%s
photosbycategory/?page_id=%s
pivhelp
place/creation
place_visit_question/help
placefeed?placeid=%s&surface=%s&placename=%s
placefeed?placeid=%s&surface=%s&placename=%s&wildcard=%s
platform_first_party
platform_first_party?cta_id=%s
platform_first_party?id={%s}&cta_id={%s}&referrer={%s}&initial_input={%s}
playground_story_embedding?storyID=%s&title=%s
playground_story_embedding_list
policies
privacy_blocking/
privacy_blocking_search/
privacy_checkup/?source=%s
privacy_composer_privacy_options/
privacy_composer_redirect_route/
privacy_enable_public_privacy_options_for_minor/
privacy_follow_privacy_options/
privacy_friend_requests_privacy_options/
privacy_friends_list_privacy_options/
privacy_limit_old_posts_privacy/
privacy_public_search/
privacy_public_search_redesign/
privacy_review_lightweight/?checkup_type=%s
privacy_search_by_email_privacy_options/
privacy_search_by_phone_privacy_options/
privacy_shortcuts/
privacy_timeline_and_tagging_content_visibility/
privacy_timeline_and_tagging_others_content_visibility/
privacy_timeline_and_tagging_settings/
privacy_timeline_and_tagging_settings_can_post/
privacy_timeline_and_tagging_settings_tag_expansion/
privacy_timeline_and_tagging_settings_tag_suggestion/
privacy_timeline_and_tagging_settings_toggle_tag_review/
privacy_timeline_and_tagging_settings_toggle_timeline_review/
privacy_touch_basic/
privacy_touch_basic_redesign/
professionalratertool
profile
profile/%s
profile/%s/activitylog
profile/%s/activitylog_search
profile/%s/activitylog_search/%s
profile/%s/friends/%s?source_ref=%s
profile/%s/info/inner
profile/%s?skip_popup=true
profile/%s?viewas=%s
profile/?extra_launch_profile_photo_selector=true
profile/?extra_launch_profile_status_edit_flow=true
profile/?profile_type=person&intro_card=edit_featured_photos
profile/fun_facts
profile/fun_facts/container_view/?profile_id=%s
profile/fun_facts/manage_prompt_view
profile/info_request/%s/%s
profile/manage_posts
profile/single_fun_fact
profile?frame_id={%s}&entry_point={%s}
profile_about?profileID=%s
profile_edit
profile_insight?id=%s
profilediscovery
profilediscovery?bucketid=%s
profilediscovery?referral_type=%s&referral_id=%s
profilediscovery?referral_type=%s&referral_id=%s&bucketid=%s
profilediscoveryfeed
profileintentdashboard
profilepictureupload
prompt/{%s}invite
qp/%s
qp/%s?data=%s
qrcode
rapid_reporting?object_id=%s
rapid_reporting?object_id=%s&location=%s
reaction-demo
registration
retail_product?product_id=%s&page_set_id=%s&ad_id=%s&ref_id=%s
retail_product?product_id=<p$1>&page_set_id=0&ad_id=0&ref_id=deeplink
reviews/?page_id=%s
reviews/?review_id=%s
reviews/?user_id=%s
rnfiddle
rnotasettings
rnregisteredroutes
rtccall/audio/
rtccall/audio/%s
salegroups
sales_promo_details/?sales_promo_id=%s
samplernintegration
saved
saved/?section_name=%s&referer=%s
saved/list/create/
saved/list/create/?surface=%s&item_id=%s
saved/list/create/?surface=%s&story_id=%s
saved/list/create/?surface=%s&url=%s
search_typeahead_results/?module=%s
search_typeahead_results/?module=%s&initial_query=%s
security_settings
seen_content/
server_snapshot_tests?q=%s&testModuleName=%s&testName=%s
settings
shops?refID=%s&refType=%s&feedType=%s
shops_feed_categories_list?refID=%s&refType=%s
shops_feed_search_route?query=%s&refID=%s&refType=%s
shops_feed_unfinished_purchase_list?refID=%s&refType=%s
shops_product_details?productID=%s&refID=%s&refType=%s&imageSizing=%s&contextID=%s&styleType=%s
silvertailsampleapp
simplestoryapp
simplestoryapp?story_id=%s
snacks_profile/bucket_id/{bucket_id}/story_id/{story_id}
snacks_sharesheet/
socialwifi/?gateway_id=%s
sports/%s
stonehenge_subscription_flow
store_locator/?north={north}&west={west}&south={south}&east={east}&ad_id={?ad_id}&page_set_id={?page_set_id}&parent_page_id={?parent_page_id}
story/%s/%s
story_privacy/
storygallerysurvey/bakeoff
storygallerysurvey/default
storyviewer/bucket_id/{bucket_id}/story_id/{story_id}
structured_menu/?page_id=%s
subscription
support
support_item?id=%s
tarot/chained_digests/?digest_ids={%s}
TEMPLATE_INSTAGRAM_USERNAME_SIGN_UP_PAGE_URL
timeline_review?highlight=<q$1>
top_live
top_live_videos
topic/%s
trust/afro/?hideable_token=%s&story_graphql_token=%s&initial_action=%s&story_location=%s&tracking=%s
trust/afro/?reportable_ent_graphql_id=%s&initial_action=%s&story_location=%s
trust/afro/?reportable_ent_token=%s&initial_action=%s&story_location=%s
video/%s?source_url=%s
video/?href={href}
video/?id={%s}
video/{%s}?source_url={href}
video_home/
video_insight?id=%s
video_notification/?notif_id={%s}&notif_cache_id={%s}
video_notification/?videoid={%s}&threadid={%s}
videochannel?id=%s
watch
watch/watchlist
weather_add_city
website_promotion/?page_id=%s&boost_id=%s&source=%s&referral=%s&restore_saved_settings=%s&coupon_promotion_group_id=%s&ad_account_id=%s&scroll_to_section=%s&request_data=%s
webview/?url=%s
work_contact_invite
work_contact_invite/?group_id=%s
work_contacts_tab
work_groups_tab
workplace_gysj
workplace_pysf
workplace_remind_unclaimed/?user_id={user_id}&name={name}
zero_dialog
```

The above is taken from the class `com.facebook.common.fblinks.FBLinks`.

Comment: Suppose these links will also break as Facebook updates their app? Still think its insane they can't allow native sharing from a webpage to the Facebook app. I mean Whatsapp does it? Which is owned by Facebook??

Comment: @Rossco - We just have to keep maintaining these lists, don't we...? :-)

Comment: @Dev-iL Fantastic list, thanks. I have a few questions about how you gathered these. Would you have time to respond to a quick email?

Comment: @novicePrgrmr - I may or may not have used methods not unlike what is described [here](http://www.technotalkative.com/part-9-reverse-engineering-android-applications/)...

Comment: How can i compose new message with text? fb://messaging/compose/%s - not working (android). I want same behavior as whatsapp's: whatsapp://send?text=

Comment: @AntonKonyushevskiy your question has nothing to do with this answer. In any case it's [**against the Facebook platform policy**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/prefill).

Comment: what are possible parameters here fb://app_section/%s/%s

Comment: @AntonKonyushevskiy did you find a solution to this? this is exactly what I want to use deep linking for as well.

Comment: @Dev-iL thank for the list. In some case, with what should we replace the %s ? (like fb://page/%s )

Comment: @Jibeee usually, the numeric ID of things. However, this is largely a matter of trial and error.

Comment: @Dev-iL thanks, it is strange because in my app, "simple " links work (i.e fb://albums or fb://profile) but impossible to make it append with "id"(fb://page/12345678) although the id is correct. It's killing my day.

Comment: fb://recent_feed opens the "most recent" page that lots of people prefer over the home feed

Comment: Currently, `fb://event/%s` works on Android but not iOS

Comment: @JustinSato You can't - these are undocumented features that you, as a developer outside fb, are not supposed to use. If this appeared in the official documentation, there was not much point to this entire Q&A, don't you think?

Comment: @Dev-iL totally agree with you

Comment: Hi @Dev-iL, is there a latest update for the schemes? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Dave The short answer is "unfortunately no". I tried generating an updated list in the years that followed the last update, but let's just say that the good folks at Meta didn't exactly make it easy. I think it might be possible to use [Frida](https://frida.re/) to extract these at runtime, but I never got around to actually doing it.

Answer (score 10):

I had a requirement where the client wanted the Social Share buttons on the website to open Facebook and Messenger native apps only. Messenger share is straightforward and documented.

For Facebook, this is a workaround that I used (Tested on Android).

```
fb://faceweb/f?href=https%3A%2F%2Fm.facebook.com%2Fsharer.php%3Fu%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com


fb://faceweb/f?href={{urlencoded sharer.php url}}
```

Comment: May you please share how you did it with Messenger?

Comment: Can confirm this no longer works anymore, unfortunately.

Comment: this still works!!! great workarround to open FB native APP via web page  and share link!!

Comment: Just tried and it still works on Android. For messenger I use `fb-messenger://share/?link={url}` and it works also on Android.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook doesn't actually guarantee these schemes [will continue working](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-sdk-swift/issues/173).  However at the time of writing this, it appears they've reverted back to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5707825/2101268)'s format.

For a while, they were matching the Android style scheme, as mentioned in the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30231726/2101268), but this is no longer true.

Use this scheme with caution, but fully expect that an update to the Facebook app might make your app no longer properly link, but rather just open the home page.