# Facebook URL scheme to post a new message from iPhone

Tags: iphone, facebook

I am developing an iPhone application, and want it to be able to post a message to Facebook, by using the Facebook app.

Is there a custom URL to do this?

I've found [this page](http://iphonedevtools.com/?p=302) that has a list of Facebook commands, but it doesn't say how to post a new message...

Comment: do you want to post the message in your wall or friends wall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707722/anyone-with-experience-working-with-iphone-facebook/5707825#5707825) ***might*** help you... Especially this : `fb://messaging/compose`

Comment: Ok, it didn't actually help, because I couldn't do what I wanted, but it is the best information I could find.

Answer (score 3):

The URL to post a new message to the wall is

```
fb://publish/?text=some text to post
```

This works with Facebook app 4.1... I don't know if it works with older versions.

Comment: This is not work on 1 July 2023

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about using a feed post then you have to do this: 
`[facebook dialog:@"feed" andDelegate:self];`

See [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#ios) for more info

Also if your making this a mobile web app then you could try this:

`http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?
    client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&display=touch`

[More info on web app](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#web)

Answer (score 0):

You could also just use [Sharekit](http://getsharekit.com/), that gives your users the option what to share. Otherwise, you'll have to use the FBDialog from the facebook-ios-sdk or a matching webview using the URL given by the other posters
The method you mention, directly calling the facebook app, a) requires the app to be installed (usually not the case on iPads, for example) and b) is not officially supported by facebook - the two other ways are.