# Anyone know how to open a fb fan page in iphone app from web page?

Tags: iphone, facebook

I'm trying to open my facebook fan page in the fbook app from a web page in safari.

I found 
[What are all the custom URL schemes supported by the Facebook iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707722/anyone-with-experience-working-with-iphone-facebook/5707825#5707825)

and I've tried setting the link to

- fb://pages/[pageid]
- fb://pages/?id=[pageid]
- fb://page/[pageid]
- fb://page/?id=[pageid]
- fb://profile/[pageid]

They all open the app( of course ) but not at my page,
I feel like i'm close but I've been poking round at it for a while now, any help much appreciated.

Comment: it's not a tab i'm after, just the page itself. This does open in both versions, and i can do it on the browser, but its the app that is really key. Mostly because iphone users tend to be logged in via the app rather than their browser

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To open facebook page in facebook app you should:

1)Find uid of your page (it can be done for example by looking at source code of your facebook page)

I got the following fragment from the source code of the page: `http://www.facebook.com/Innova.et.Bella`

```
{"text":"Innova et Bella","type":"ent:page","uid":73728918115}
```

N.B.: To check if uid is correct substitute uid for pagename:   `http://www.facebook.com/73728918115`
This url should open your page.

2) When the uid is found end is correct use this code:

```
NSURL *urlApp = [NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://profile/73728918115"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:urlApp];
```

This code will open you page within facebook app. 
N.B.: Do not forget to check if the facebook app exists( or more precisely that the url can be opened) using: if `([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:urlApp])` otherwise open it in Safari.

Answer (score -2):

Facebook tab pages do not displayed in the mobile or app version of facebook. Not possible.

Comment: it's not a tab i'm after, just the page itself. This does open in both versions, and i can do it on the browser, but its the app that is really key. Mostly because iphone users tend to be logged in via the app rather than their browser