# Custom URL Scheme for sharing URL in native Facebook iPhone App

Tags: ios, facebook

I know the available custom URL schemes for the native Facebook iPhone App:

[What are all the custom URL schemes supported by the Facebook iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707722/what-are-all-the-custom-url-schemes-supported-by-the-facebook-iphone-app)

But I can't find a way to publish a URL to my wall / timeline in that way, that Facebook collects / shows the site title and thumbnail as it does with the touch.facebook.com/sharer.php file.

The only way I see so far is to call

```
fb://publish/?text=www.domain.com
```

but this only post the link to my timeline, not title, thumbnail and site description.

Does anyone know a better way?

Answer (score -2):

Basically you have two options:

You can either launch Safari using the Feed Dialog URL Scheme as explained [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) or use Facebook SDK as explained [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/publish-to-feed-ios-sdk/).

If your App isn't integrated with Facebook already, it's probably easier to go with the first one.

Comment: The Share Dialog URL Scheme was super useful to me! Thanks