# Share in Facebook app using URL scheme

Tags: android, html, ios, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to create a HTML link that [shares a text through the Facebook app using URL scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10227370/2684718). This link will be accessed by mobile, Android and iOS.

```
<a href="fb://publish/?text=http://google.com">Share</a>
```

When I click this link on my Android phone, the Facebook app opens but does nothing! What is wrong here?

Comment: I'd guess Android uses intents instead of URL schemes.

Comment: Can I call the Facebook app using a HTML link?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open Facebook page from Android app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810803/open-facebook-page-from-android-app)

Comment: @ceejayoz No, this is not duplicated! I'm trying to share a link from the browser, not from an app.

Comment: Then you should be using https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog.

Comment: @ceejayoz So, please remove the "duplicated" annotation.

Comment: _“What is wrong here?”_ – what you are trying to do is wrong here. Apps are not allowed to pre-fill the text of a share/post. Go read FB Platform Policy, please.

Comment: @CBroe I'm not trying to pre-fill using an app. I'm trying to share a link from a mobile web page running on the browser.

Comment: Then you have to use the official methods that pass the link as an extra parameter (no, don’t ask me if that works with those schemes) – if you make it part of the message that is shared, it is pre-filling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Facebook URL Schemes shift a lot, and their functionality is generally not well documented. There was an attempt to catalog them at
[What are all the custom URL schemes supported by the Facebook iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707722/what-are-all-the-custom-url-schemes-supported-by-the-facebook-iphone-app)

If you can settle for opening the dialog in the browser, you can use the Share Dialog:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog