# UILocalnotification firing even after notification is cancelled

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

The notification is firing even after it is cancelled. I tried checking cancelling method it turned out to be correct.

When I cancel a notification, the notification is again fired the next day

```
- (void)cancelNotification:(int)bookID
{
    NSArray *notifications = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];
    NSLog(@"Cancelling... Before %d",[[[UIApplication sharedApplication]scheduledLocalNotifications]count]);

    for (UILocalNotification *notification in notifications)
    {

        int notifRemedyId = [[notification.userInfo objectForKey:@"kRemindMeNotificationRemedyIDKey"]intValue];

        NSLog(@"remedyID  : %d",remedyId);
        NSLog(@"notifyId : %d",notifRemedyId);
        if (remedyId == notifRemedyId)
        {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notification];
        }

    }

}
```

I am thinking its because of repeatInterval.should repeatInterval property be removed.

SO I wanted to know where I am going wrong.

Comment: shouldn't you use [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications]; ?

Comment: Log your values and see what you're getting.

Comment: @HotLicks i have figured out the problem I wasn't archiving the notification which was cancelled in viewdidload. So if notification was cancelled the app wasn't getting updated which notification was cancelled.

Answer (score 0):

**1)** First check retrieved particular notification object is not *nil*. Also check if that is the notification you want to cancel.

**2)** When you are sure notification object is not *nil* and the notification is the *desired one*, then fire below command. **notification** is your desired notification object.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notification];
```

**3)** I am looking at your code and I could see that you are not using `bookID` notification anywhere in your code. Not sure if you are using that code anymore.

**4)** No, you don't need to do anything extra to cancel repeating notification

**Note:** Please update your Question with final updated code. This looks confusing.

Comment: I have added schedule Notification method

Comment: Which method is cancelling the notification ?

Comment: check your `cancelNotification` method. Where are you using `bookID` ? I don't see it anywhere being used.

Comment: i have put it as bookID just didnt wanted to post my actual code.

Comment: Just go through all the points I have mentioned. That should solve the problem.

Comment: i have done the exact same thing as u have mentioned in ur points

Comment: I will sure. What was the problem ?

Comment: No no, I was asking about this post, notification not being cancelled. What was the problem ?

Comment: Ya, I will help you on another post. But I want to know what was the problem with this one ? How did you resolve ?

Comment: I wasn't archiving the notification which was cancelled in viewdidload. So if notification was cancelled the app wasn't getting updated which notification was cancelled

Comment: Sure I will once I get some free time :)