# Initiate Facebook Group Chat from iOS App

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, chat, messaging

I want my app to create a new Facebook group chat with certain people that opens either on Facebook's site in Safari or in the native Facebook app when the user presses a button. I want Facebook to handle the whole chat and my app only to initiate it somehow in the cleanest and least involved way possible. My app already uses the Facebook SDK to open an active FBSession, so I've already got login credentials.

Looking around online and in Facebook's docs, I can't find anything that suits my needs. The closest thing I found was in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707722/what-are-all-the-custom-url-schemes-supported-by-the-facebook-iphone-app/5707825#5707825) containing a list of Facebook app URLs you can connect to that open the Facebook app to certain pages. There's "fb://chat/(initWithUID:)" and "fb://messaging/compose/(initWithUID:)". However, not only is there no explanation on how to use these, but people say that Facebook has changed these URLs (and does not have any documentation on them), so they don't work anymore unless I reverse-engineer new URLs (which could change again). Ugh, so close!

I also found examples on starting chats with the Facebook Chat API, but that involves logging into Facebook using some networking framework then writing my own GUI and model for sending messages, which I am only prepared to do as a last resort. There should be some way to let the Facebook app or website do all that. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

I've found something very close, but I still don't see a way to make my app initialize it with the desired group of friends:

The Facebook SDK has a message dialog that can appear for sending messages to friends. This isn't exactly what I wanted but is good enough because it means that all the programming is already done for me by Facebook, and users should be able to see these messages on https://facebook.com and the Facebook apps. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share#message-dialog

Answer (score -1):

I can tell you what worked for me, what i did was this created a group text message (also known as a group chat) on your iPhone, follow these steps:-

**1. Open Messages App:-** Launch the Messages app on your iPhone. It's the green speech bubble icon.

**2. Start a New Message:-** Tap on the compose button located in the upper-right corner of the screen. It looks like a pencil and paper icon.

**3. Add Contacts to the Message:-** In the "To:" field, start typing the name or phone number of the contacts you want to add to the group message. As you type, your iPhone will suggest contacts from your address book. Tap on a contact to add them to the group message. You can add multiple contacts to create the group.

**4. Create the Group:-** Once you've added all the contacts you want to include in the group message, tap on the "Create Group" button at the top of the screen.

**5. Compose Your Message:-** Now, you can compose your message in the text field at the bottom of the screen. Type your message, then tap the send button (the blue arrow icon) to send the message to all the contacts in the group.

**6. Sending a Group Message to Existing Contacts:-** If you want to start a group message with contacts you've previously messaged, you can do so by opening the existing conversation thread with one of the contacts, tapping the group icon (which looks like the silhouette of three people) in the top-right corner of the screen, and then adding additional contacts to the group.
Follow for more details assistance below.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z2RT_UqFoCY&ab_channel=TheGeekPage

Comment: did you use any generative AI at all in the writing of this answer post?

Comment: @Nicky0555, AI generated content is against site policy. (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1) Please refrain from passing AI generated content as your own work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).