# Open facebook page link in browser or native app correctly IOS cordova

Tags: javascript, ios, facebook, cordova, inappbrowser

Previous question on this similar topic isn't working for me and most of them are unanswered.

I want to take the user to a facebook page with button click.
Updated facebook is installed in iphone, latest cordova is installed, inappbrowser plugin is used.
Now my code is

```
window.open('https://www.facebook.com/latechnologies', '_system','location=yes');
```

This works perfectly on android. But in IOS link is catched by nation facebook app and take me to the facebook wall of the use not the page feed. That means it just open the native app,but don't take to any page.

Then I searched, and tried some suggestions

```
window.open('fb://facebook.com/latechnologies', '_system','location=yes');

window.open('fb://pages/latechnologies', '_system','location=yes');

window.open('fb://pages', '_system','location=yes');
```

None of them are working. Every time it takes to the user wall. How can I simply take the user to the facebook page? Native app or browser doesn't matter. Just want to take the user to the page.....................

Comment: @kathir cordova 3.4.1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For me using the Facebook page id instead of the page name works fine, e.g.

```
window.open('https://www.facebook.com/1401408870089080', '_system');
```

Comment: This works only with numeric IDs, here's a tool you can use to get that ID: http://findmyfacebookid.com/

Comment: Opens in browser ; not in the FB app.

Comment: It stops working when facebook app is available. any suggestion ? Tried 'fb://pages/1401408870089080' but not working.

Comment: here I found the new list for IOS native app page open.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707722/what-are-all-the-custom-url-schemes-supported-by-the-facebook-iphone-app/5707825#5707825

Answer (score 4):

I know this is old but I had this problem too, and the accepted answer is through the browser, not through the FB app.

**Answer = `fb://profile/12323435435`**

On IOS pages are under 'profile'

```
fb://profile/   - FOR IOS
fb://page/      - FOR ANDROID

    <a onclick="window.open('fb://profile/INSERT_FB_ID_HERE','_system')"> 
                                        Your text or button here </a>
```

You can find a FB profile or page here : https://findmyfbid.com

Answer (score 0):

Open up your MainViewController.m file.

Insert this code after @implementation and before @end MainViewController.

```
- (BOOL) webView:(UIWebView*)theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSURL *url = [request URL];

    // Intercept the external http requests and forward to Safari.app
    // Otherwise forward to the PhoneGap WebView
    if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"http"] || [[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"https"]){
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
        return NO;
    }
    else {
        return [super webView:theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request navigationType:navigationType];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a plugin to open Apps:
org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser 0.5.4 "InAppBrowser"

After that you must to know what is the Facebook Page Id, for this:
https://graph.facebook.com/latechnologies

Take the ID number and replace the username of the Fanpage:
https://www.facebook.com/1382616721988023

In that's all... ;)

Like Jonas's Answer! Different method! :)

Comment: Don't you think your answer and jonas's answer are exactly the same!

Comment: Sorry i try to help you. :) if you know about the InAppBrowser plugin i will delete my amswer. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

After trying a few iterations and few of the suggestions above, the following code worked for me.
    window.open('fb://pages/, '_system');

The above is intended to open the page on facebook app (if it is installed).

Ofcourse, I have installed cordova inappbrowser plugin.