# How to open facebook app-scoped id on iOS Custom URL

Tags: ios, facebook

I want to open facebook user profile page on iOS facebook App from my apps using Custom URL.

```
"fb://profile/{id}" is working, but

"fb://profile/{app-scoped-id}" is not working.
```

**Edit 1** (7/7 20:53)

Detail of "is not working":
It is open facebook app, but does not show profile page. The app shows last window (ex feed).

Comment: You should clarify what you mean by "is not working", so that we can help you better.

Comment: Try this one, maybe different: `fb://profile?id=%@`, taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707722

Comment: @Neeku I'm sorry... I appended information, please read it.

Comment: @VincentGuerci Thank you! ```fb://profile?id=%@``` is not working. but ```fb://profile?app_scoped_user_id=%@``` is worked!!

Comment: @KomatsuIssei Glad you find your answer, which I posted, if you can accept it.. ;)

Comment: have you found solution for same?

Comment: @Maulikpatel Sorry, I have never found :(

Answer (score 1):

You have a list of available url handlers from Facebook app in that SO question:

> [What are all the custom URL schemes supported by the Facebook iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707722)

Maybe `fb://profile?id=%@` will have a different behavior.

**EDIT**: From your comment: `fb://profile?app_scoped_user_id=%@` works.

Comment: Sorry, it was not worked. It shows only own profile.

Comment: I try other method inspired by your comment.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the bug report on https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/332195860270199 opening the Facebook profile with fb://profile?app_scoped_user_id=%@ is not supported.

You will have to open the Facebook profile within Safari (http://facebook.com/%@). It's annoying but works as a workaround ...

Maybe you could comment under the bug report that you need this feature like I did.

Instead of using Safari you could also use an in app web browser. This it what I'll try.

Comment: I have added my facebook account as tester role in developer portal.  Your provided solution not working for it. is it something related to roles?
p.s. I am testing app in development mode