# Is there any way to specify facebook-links with the HTTP protocol which opens the app (iPhone/Androdi) if installed?

Tags: facebook, url-scheme

So I know the Facebook-app supports the [fb:// URL scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707722/what-are-all-the-custom-url-schemes-supported-by-the-facebook-iphone-app). But does it also support a URL scheme for HTTP?

I've tried for instance `https://www.facebook.com/Google`, and it does not yield an option to open the app, when clicked on from Chrome on an HTC One M8 device. So obviously Facebook haven't defined a URL scheme to match that URL. But they might have created others? Theoretically they could for instance have a scheme that triggered when a sub-url contains `/app` or something.

My goal is to link to a Facebook profile page which opens in the app if it is installed, and in the browser if not. Without using any Javascript. If facebook have defined a schema matching any HTTP-protocol, it is possible.

Answer (score 2):

I made this work for link to google play with this function, changing te protocol to the facebook could work

```
public void getpro(View view) {
    final String appName = BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID;
    try {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id="+appName")));
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="+appName")));
    }
}
```

to:

```
public void getpro(View view) {
    try {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("facebook://facebook.com/inbox")));
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.facebook.com")));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to achieve this with Intents. I found this:

```
String uri = "facebook://facebook.com/inbox";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
startActivity(intent);
```

Intent is used to call other applications while using an application.

Comment: This is fine, but I want it to work outside apps as well - from Chrome for Android.