# URL Scheme to open a post in facebook app

Tags: ios, facebook, url-scheme

How do I use the url scheme to open a facebook post in facebook ios app?

I got a thing while goolgling like "fb://post/"id""

but it does not work, it just opened the facebook app.

Answer (score 0):

http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes

This "works" but, then again, doesn't:
    fb://post/
    It only works if the Facebook app has previously loaded the particular post, otherwise it draws a blank.

Answer (score -1):

u can use this link. this might help you

[What are all the custom URL schemes supported by the Facebook iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707722/what-are-all-the-custom-url-schemes-supported-by-the-facebook-iphone-app)

fb://profile – Open Facebook app to the user’s profile

fb://friends – Open Facebook app to the friends list

fb://feed – Open Facebook app to the News Feed

fb://events – Open Facebook app to the Events page

fb://requests – Open Facebook app to the Requests list

fb://notes- Open Facebook app to the Notes page

fb://albums – - Open Facebook app to Photo Albums list

Comment: But none of them covers opening a particular `post` :(