# Open iOS FB app with URL Schema

Tags: ios, facebook, swift2

I am investigating ways to open the FB app using a URL Schema. I want to open my app directly to the Search Page and automatically fill the search bar. I am not seeing the search page covered in the URL Schemas:

[URL Scheme to open a post in facebook app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29888701/url-scheme-to-open-a-post-in-facebook-app)

Currently, my app is able to go to the search page by creating a custom hyperlink through code and launching Safari. However, most people are not logged into FB through Safari so this causes me issues.

Any thoughts?

Comment: There are no supported ways to do that

Comment: Thanks for the response @WizKid. Is there a particularly reason and do you have any suggested workarounds?

Comment: A lot of url schema here check this one :[All facebook ios schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707722/what-are-all-the-custom-url-schemes-supported-by-the-facebook-iphone-app)