# Find iOS appNames to launch via javascript

Tags: javascript, ios

I've searched and [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707722/what-are-all-the-custom-url-schemes-supported-by-the-facebook-iphone-app) that to open Facebook it is:

```
window.location = "fb://";         /* It works fine   */
```

Instead of:

```
window.location = "facebook://";   /* It doesn't work */
```

The problem is:

I need to open an app like "facebook", but I don't know *how to find* the *appName* URL Scheme like `fb://` is for "Facebook"...

I've tried a lot of name combinations, but without success.

I would be glad if you could give me some hint to achieve this.

Comment: There's no Apple-maintained registry, to my knowledge. Try http://handleopenurl.com/

Comment: Are you looking to "find" and launch your own app, or a different specific app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Palpatim said, you can look at an online registry, such as [this one](http://handleopenurl.com/).

Otherwise, there is no way to get this scheme programatically in Javascript. You can find it by hand if you open an `.ipa` file, in `Payload/*appName.app/Info.plist`. You'll see a list of urls like this:

[image: URLs]

This picture for example will respond to `product://`.

Be aware that opening an .ipa file might be considered reverse engineering, so only do this on your own apps.

Comment: By the way, I forgot to say that *some apps do not support URL Schemes*. That means there is no way to open them from anywhere else, sorry...

Answer (score -2):

Because the Facebook is known as fb so they have coded it like that so maybe the main function can change it