# Facebook URL scheme for opening a post

Tags: ios, facebook, swift

I don't think what I'm looking for is in this page: [What are all the custom URL schemes supported by the Facebook iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707722/what-are-all-the-custom-url-schemes-supported-by-the-facebook-iphone-app/5707825#5707825)

I don't think a complete, detailed list is in Facebook Developers website (not like [Instagram](https://instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/iphone-hooks/)), too. I could be wrong; if I am, could someone provide it here, please?

If I have a post id, say `10153489686678735`, what `fb://` schema should I use? I tried `story`, `post`, `topic`, but they just load my Facebook app's news feed.

Answer (score 0):

There is no official support for external developers to use the custom URL schemes of the Facebook iOS app, so even if you would find out how to open a specific post, profile, page or other piece of content, it might break any second with no fix and your app experience would be broken.