# URL scheme for showing a facebook video in ios app

Tags: ios, facebook

Does anyone know the URL scheme for iOS to show a video in the facebook app?

For showing the profile I use

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://profile/1727305929"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

What is similar for a video?
For example, what is the URL scheme for this video link:

> https://www.facebook.com/hanwel/videos/10200653642859965/?pnref=story

Thanks,

Hanno

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are all the custom URL schemes supported by the Facebook iPhone app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707722/what-are-all-the-custom-url-schemes-supported-by-the-facebook-iphone-app)

Comment: unfortunately not, most of these schemes are not working. The only one I can use is profile/id.

Comment: Did you scroll down to the May 2015 update?

Comment: This functionality is not officially supported. You should not rely on this functionality.

Comment: Thanks, that's also the result of my researches. So I will link to the web url of Facebook and let Safari do the job.