# Xamarin.IOS -> How to interact with sharing to Facebook, Whatsup, etc

Tags: xamarin.ios

I have an app where I wanna share some content to facebook, whatsup, mail and message. How do I interact with the native apps installed on the users phone. It would be something like the Implicit Intent for Xamarin.Android.
I'm using MVVM Cross.
Any help to guide me to the right direction is appreciated.
Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `Intents` in Android and `URL Schemes` in iOS to accomplish this. You can find the information you need on the developer portals:

### **Android**

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android

http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html

### iOS

[What are all the custom URL schemes supported by the Facebook iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707722/what-are-all-the-custom-url-schemes-supported-by-the-facebook-iphone-app/5707825#5707825)

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW1