# Processing to MessageComposer via facebook

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I try to work with Facebook friends and want to send message from my app to some friends.

Note: Bad news - I found information that now this functionality deprecated.

But found some information about it [custom URL schemes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707722/what-are-all-the-custom-url-schemes-supported-by-the-facebook-iphone-app/5707825#5707825).

Does Facebook support some url schema for sending message to user?
Can I setup "user_id", "text message" or image and send this message from Facebook native app?

Comment: No, if this was added, people would abuse this functionality.