# Facebook URL scheme needed.

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, jailbreak, traversal

Hi I am trying to find a url scheme to open the Facebook feed to most recent. I have looked through the various sites including this one http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes and can't find one. I am trying to use it on iOS jailbroken using the app called Traverse so it can be added as a force touch option when long pressing on the Facebook app icon.

Comment: there is one in that site mentioned clearly for facebook. Please look again!!!!

Comment: http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#Facebook

Comment: It opens feed to top stories not most recent.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are all the custom URL schemes supported by the Facebook iPhone app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707722/what-are-all-the-custom-url-schemes-supported-by-the-facebook-iphone-app)

Comment: Thank you  @BjörnKaiser that is a full list. Still can't find what I am looking for so I assume that there is no way to open feed to most recent with a url scheme.

Comment: In general you should never rely on such lists as this is not officially supported by Facebook and might break without prior notice