# In Cordova/Ionic, How to open a Facebook profile link in the native app?

Tags: ios, facebook, cordova, facebook-graph-api, ionic-framework

I am trying to open a user's profile in the native Facebook app on ios, if installed. The app is built on Cordova/Ionic and I use ngCordova inAppBrowser plugin.

Twitter links, for example, work just fine with a regular web twitter link (https://twitter.com/[username]). Facebook on the other hand, do not.
I have tried many different variations:

- https://www.facebook.com/[username/user_id]
- https://facebook.com/[username/user_id]
- fb://profile/[username/user_id]
- fb://profile?id=[user_id]

None worked.

What am I doing wrong? Is it even possible with the current version of the Facebook app?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Just use: 'fb://profile'

In my case worked for both Android and iOS:

```
$scope.openFb = function() {
  $window.open('fb://profile', "_system");
};
```

See this answer for further reference on custom url schemes supported by Facebook iPhone app:

[What are all the custom URL schemes supported by the Facebook iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707722/what-are-all-the-custom-url-schemes-supported-by-the-facebook-iphone-app)

Comment: That scheme only works for your own profile, not for opening any user profile.

Comment: Definitely used to work, but fb updated the app and the API, although I can't find the new schemes. If you do so, please be so kind to update my answer or leave a comment.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
fb://profile?id=[username|user_id]
```

I've tested on Safari, it works as expected,