# Open Facebook event page in webview with authenticated user

Tags: ios, facebook, uiwebview

I logged in through the Facebook app. Now I want to show events in UIWebView. when I sent the Url to UIWebView, it ask for Facebook login. But I am already logged from the app.

I don't have any idea how to pass access token in UIWebView and retrieve that event page with authenticated user.

Comment: Sharing login information between the native FB app and the browser is not possible.

Comment: @CBroe Is there any other way to login with authenticated Facebook user in UIWebview?

Comment: No, there is not. / As an alternative, look at the URL schemes the FB app offers, maybe you can open it directly inside the app instead. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707722/what-are-all-the-custom-url-schemes-supported-by-the-facebook-iphone-app

Comment: @CBroe If i will logged in through the safari, then is there any way to pass access token to UiwebView?

Comment: Not that I know of; a webview is a separate component, and has little to do with the “normal” browser.

Comment: @CBroe thanks for your support

Comment: @CBroe is there any way to display the event page of Facebook within the app so that user does not need to leave the app. By URL scheme, it takes to the facebook app and then display the event page.