# Open Facebook app in profile picture upload on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm struggling to make my app open the Profile Picture upload screen of the Facebook App just like the Prisma App is doing on the latest update.

[Prisma App example - image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpxCG.jpg)

[Facebook Profile Picture Upload - image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxMJG.jpg)

I was trying to use the URLs Schemes (like the "fb://profile/", basically all of the [listed schemes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30231726/6766005)). I came up with these two.

> "fb://nux/profile_picture?external_photo_source=%s"
>
> "fb://profilepictureupload"

and opened these url schemes in my iOS App using:

```
    let url = NSURL(string: "fb://nux/profile_picture?external_photo_source=\(savePath)")!
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
```

This is not documented on the Facebook Developer page, so I'm completely lost with this issue. Thank you guys! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must not use URL Scheme:) This feature is implemented by this Facebook SDK https://developers.facebook.com/products/profile-expression-kit