# Is it possible to deep link to a Facebook Event page?

Tags: iphone, facebook, ios10, deep-linking

I've tried fb://event/EventID#Here which attempts to open the event page in the Facebook app, but then says "Unable to load event. It may have been cancelled." Obviously I didn't cancel the event, and it isn't Private or Guest View only. Is this function simply not supported in iOS 10?

If not, what Facebook deep links *are* supported? I've only had success with Profiles and Pages, but this post has quite a large list that supposedly work: [What are all the custom URL schemes supported by the Facebook iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707722/what-are-all-the-custom-url-schemes-supported-by-the-facebook-iphone-app/5707825#5707825) (hasn't been updated for iOS 10 though)

Comment: There is no supported deep links

Comment: why the downvote? It's a perfectly legal question.

Answer (score 4):

fb://event?id=[eventID] appears to work

Answer (score 0):

deeplinks are supported now, your link should be `https://facebook.com/events/:eventId/`

Answer (score 0):

For me, @Wes answer did not work. Only seems to run with `fb://event/:eventId`
Maybe the API changed...