# Post a message to Facebook using Facebook URL scheme on mobiles

Tags: javascript, android, ios, facebook, url-scheme

From the website, I need to have a share button which will share some text to a user's wall through FACEBOOK APP.

I tried Facebook Javascript SDK, but it sometimes opens share in a new window instead of forcing on Facebook app.

So, I am trying to do this through Facebook Url scheme.

I have tried all of these but none of them worked.

```
fb://publish/?text=test
fb://post/test
fb://dialog/feed?app_id=fb_app_id&display=touch&href=test
fb://publish/post/?text=test
```

[What are all the custom URL schemes supported by the Facebook iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707722/what-are-all-the-custom-url-schemes-supported-by-the-facebook-iphone-app/5707825#5707825)

Can you please help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is none. Because you are not allowed to prefill the message

Answer (score 1):

This was working for me:

```
url = `fbapi://dialog/share?app_id=${fbid}&version=20130410&method_args=`
let methodArgs = {
  name: null,
  description: null,
  link: value,
  quote: null,
  hashtag: null,
  dataFailuresFatal: false
}

url += encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(methodArgs))
```

Where 'fbid' is your facebook app ID.
And 'value' is the URL you want to share.

Then do something like:

```
<a href="url">Share link on facebook</a>
```