# iOS Facebook App URL schemes in 2017

Tags: ios, facebook

What are the URL schemes supported by the newest (October 2017) Version of iOS Facebook app?

I tried [older URL schemes and schemes from Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707722/what-are-all-the-custom-url-schemes-supported-by-the-facebook-iphone-app) but only "fb://profile?id=" is working.