# webview open native fb app in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, webview

on a webview with this custom scheme type:

```
case "whatsapp":
     #if DEBUG
      print("this is whatsapp")
     #endif
     openCustomApp(urlScheme: "whatsapp://", additional_info: url_elements[1])
            decisionHandler(.cancel)
```

how can I adapt this to facebook?

I tried to replace whatsapp:// with fb:// and in plist at LSApplicationQueriesSchemes I set string to fb

It still opens a url in safari.

Comment: Can you try with full URI scheme as such fb://MODULE_NAME, you can find all supported modules in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/30231726/1244597, for example, fb://recent_feed to open the "most recent" page that I prefer over the home feed ))

Comment: Can u post how you added `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can't just open the facebook app, you need to pass a parameter for a profile or page id like:

```
fb://profile/<id>
```

and for pages it's:

```
fb://page/<id>
```

You can test if the device is able to open a specific url using:

```
UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string: "fb://"))
```

Comment: indeed, I have the url on the page that the webview is loading, it is fb://profile/<id> as in fb://profile/5550296508 (CNN) and it doesn't work.