# How to open Facebook page with Branch.io link

Tags: android, facebook, branch.io

I am using Branch.io link to open my facebook page in the android app. If app is installed then open app otherwise redirect to facebook page in the browser. I am using this link in emails signature.
Currently, the link opening the facebook app in android & but opens the default facebook user newsfeed not my page. It's working fine in iOS.
I'm using the following format to open the facebook.

```
fb://page/?id=my_facebook_page_id
```

If it is working in iOS then why not in Android. Please help.
P.S.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fb://page/my_facebook_page_id` seems to work

Please note that this is not the recommended method for deep linking as this URL scheme isn't officially listed on any of Facebook's documentation. This is a hacky solution based on answers to other similar questions on StackOverflow. [Reference- [What are all the custom URL schemes supported by the Facebook iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707722/what-are-all-the-custom-url-schemes-supported-by-the-facebook-iphone-app/5707825#5707825) ]

Comment: As of April 2021, this doesn't appear to work any more.