# Branch.IO - Link to Facebook Group

Tags: branch.io

I'm in marketing and hoping someone here can provide some guidance. I have been searching for a solution that will allow potential customers to click on a link present in an advertisement and have the link open our Facebook Group in their FB app. Today, the mobile web browser takes over.

I've been researching this for some time and recently found Branch.IO. I'm just not sure the best approach to take to accomplish my goal. Most of the examples I've seen are to launch a companies mobile app with deep linking to a product. I suppose this is similar but the app is Facebook and the deep link is to our group.

If someone would be willing to assist I would be very appreciative. Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at this: https://pureoxygenlabs.com/deep-linking-to-group-pages-in-the-facebook-mobile-app/. Seems like you can link `fb://group/?id=xyz` and that will deep link into the Facebook app, as you requested. You could even do this through Branch I believe, just set it as your URI Scheme under Link Settings.

Answer (score 0):

For Facebook app to be opened consistently, you would need to integrate Branch SDK into the app. Since you do not have access to Facebook's code base - you will not be able to do this. 
The setup is still possible with Branch, but you would have to rely on the URI schemes provided here: [What are all the custom URL schemes supported by the Facebook iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707722/what-are-all-the-custom-url-schemes-supported-by-the-facebook-iphone-app)

You may utilize [Branch's integration guide](https://docs.branch.io/pages/dashboard/integrate/) for best integration results.

However, you may be better off using a simple link shortener of some sort to direct users to your Facebook group on web.