# Opening up specific posts inside Facebook app?

Tags: facebook

There doesn't seem to be a clear answer on whether its possible to open up a specific Facebook post (from a page) inside the app when clicking to it from outside the app.

Like if I link to https://www.facebook.com/facebook/photos/pcb.10158175689716729/10158175682471729/

I want it to open up in the app (on IOS and Android).

But it doesn't, it just opens up the page for Facebook.

Is there a specific way to format the link so it does?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707722/what-are-all-the-custom-url-schemes-supported-by-the-facebook-iphone-app