# Invoke Facebook camera from a mobile browser URL

Tags: javascript, facebook, camera, deep-linking, webintents

I am trying to invoke the Facebook camera on click of a link in mobile browser.

I tried using FB custom url schemes.

```
<a href="fb://camera">Facebook Page</a>
```

But it is not invoking the Facebook Camera. I have used other custom url Ex: `<a href="http://facebook.com/pagename" data-scheme="fb://page/pageID">Facebook Page</a>` which is working as expected. on click it is opening the app and redirecting to particular page if app is installed.

Comment: Where did you get `fb://camera` from?

Comment: There is a list of custom URL schemes supported by FB. I found few of them from the below link. [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707722/what-are-all-the-custom-url-schemes-supported-by-the-facebook-iphone-app). I am not sure if all the links provided were still supoorted by FB but few of them are are working.