# How to open a particular Facebook post from IOS app. not a facebook page. correct url scheme to open a facebook post?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I'm trying to open a facebook post from ios app.

I referred [What are all the custom URL schemes supported by the Facebook iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707722/what-are-all-the-custom-url-schemes-supported-by-the-facebook-iphone-app)

But there is no direct answer to the question.

How can I create a url scheme to a facebook post by using `fb://photos/` or `fb://post/`  ?

Any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to open a facebook image by `fb://photo?id=(postId)`.

Use `fb://profile/(postId)`for share a post.

Answer (score 0):

to open a specific facebook post you can try:

```
fb://profile/(postID)
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Feb 2021, the url you copy directly via Facebook app (when you click on Share) can be used directly in your app to open the post in FB iOS app.

Note: Just replace the 'web' in url with 'www' if there is any.

[image]