# How to make facebook share button to user facebook application

Tags: javascript, facebook

How can I make a button on my website when someone from a mobile device clicks on the button to share the link via Facebook app NOT via browser ?

This code works for Facebook messenger application.

```
   $('.messenger').click(function(){
      window.open('fb-messenger://share?link=' + encodeURIComponent(link) + '&app_id=' + encodeURIComponent(app_id));
    })
```

I tried to change the code to the code below but the code below is only opening the Facebook application without insert sharing link

```
$('.fb-app').click(function(){
  window.open('fb://share?link=' + encodeURIComponent(link) + '&app_id=' + encodeURIComponent(app_id));
})
```

Comment: i believe if you have facebook apps installed it will have default links associated to FB to opens using the app by default, have you tried it?

Comment: also there could be chance your link or app id is incorrect, can you provide the final string passed to the window.open?

Comment: try this `fb-share-link://share?link=https://www.example.com"`

Answer (score 2):

From the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51239012/929187), may still work:

```
$('.fb-app').click(function(){
  window.open('fb://faceweb/f?href=' + 
    encodeURIComponent('https://m.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=' + 
      encodeURIComponent(link)));
})
```

Answer (score -1):

This might work.
$('.fb-app').click(function(){
var link = 'https://www.example.com';  // Replace with the link you want to share
var app_id = '123456789';  // Replace with your Facebook app ID
window.open('fb://share?link=' + encodeURIComponent(link) + '&app_id=' + encodeURIComponent(app_id));
});